# Button in a DataGrid column, getting the cell values of row from which it came on the Click event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

xml:Button in my datagrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Update">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Update" Name="btnEmpGridUpdate" Tag="{Binding Path = EMPID}" Click="btnEmpGridUpdate_Click" ></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

code in button event :

```
Object Id = new Object();
Id =  ((Button)sender).Tag;
```

Is that a possible way to retrieve all cell's value of a selected row ? If , how can I do this ? Or else , please suggest me some other way to update in my dataset from datagrid. Thanks in advance . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these helper functions;
http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html

On your Update button, hook up Click event, and in the handler, do something like this:

```
//youll need to google for GetVisualParent function.
DataGridRow row = GetVisualParent<DataGridRow>(button);
for(int j = 0; j < dataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
   DataGridCell cell = GetCell(dataGrid, row, j);
```

I didn't completely understand what you wanted to do, but this should help.

Comment: the link is pretty helpful ! Thanks :-)

Comment: Don't make your answers dependent on external resources, try to get all the necessary information into your answer to make it stand on its own. I just got a 503 from that link.